# How can I incporporate a Geolocation lookup into a switch?

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, switch-statement

In my Wordpress theme I have a function that looks a bit like this:

```
function variable($value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 'prem_no':
            $prem_no_uk  = '0906 636 4355';
            $prem_no_aus = '';
            $prem_no_us  = '';
            return $prem_no;
            break;
    }
}
```

On the page I am calling:

```
echo variable('prem_no');
```

I want to use this script to get the users location, and depending on the returning location, return one of the three variables listed in the case above.
http://www.hostip.info/use.html

the problem I have, is I've looked on that site, and it just gives a URL. I don't know how to write an IF statement, or whatever is needed.

I think logically, I want to only have one call for the main location finder, then store that value as a variable elsewhere on the site.

Then in the return for the cases add a suffix at the end of prem_no that would match the cases above.

Is that along the right tracks?

UPDATE:

Right I'll try and have a go in a slightly different direction.

At the top of the header file I've got this:

```
require_once 'geoip.inc';
$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat',GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
```

I'm getting a error message saying:

> Warning: fopen(GeoIP.dat): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant\geoip.inc on line 314

What I don't get is that the path is absolutely correct, the file is there. So why can't it find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've managed to partly fix my issues here.

I put the switch and the code into a single function like this:

```
function variable($value) {
$country_code = '';
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open(dirname(__FILE__)."/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
switch ($value) {
    case 'prem_no':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $prem_no = '888-888-8888'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AU') { $prem_no = '1900 000 000'; }
        else { $prem_no  = '0906 636 4355'; }
        return $prem_no;
        break;


    case 'prem_rate':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $prem_rate = '$3.50'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $prem_rate = '$3.96'; } 
        else { $prem_rate  = '£1.53'; }
        return $prem_rate;
        break;

    case 'local_no':
        if ($country_code == 'US') { $local_no = '755-555-5555'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $local_no = '1800 000 000'; } 
        else { $local_no  = '0207 111 6311'; }
        return $local_no;
        break;


    case 'sms_no':
        if($country_code == 'AUS') { $sms_no = '1977 1977'; } 
        else { $sms_no  = '78887'; }
        return $sms_no;
        break;

    case 'sms_rate':
        if($country_code == 'AUS') { $sms_rate = '25c'; } 
        else { $sms_rate  = '£1.50'; }
        return $sms_rate;
        break;

    case 'helpline':
        if($country_code == 'US') { $helpline = '700-777-7777'; }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AUS') { $helpline = '1700 000 000'; }
        else { $helpline  = '0207 111 6210'; }
        return $helpline;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

The file GeoIP.dat loads perfectly fine on every normal page, except when looking at the blog pages. (I'm assuming it must read functions differently or something? The error I get when trying to view the Blog loop articles is:

> Warning: fopen(GeoIP.dat): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\wp-content\themes\clairvoyant\geoip.inc on line 314

then at the bottom of the trace table it says

> Can not open GeoIP.dat

I just can't work out why it's working fine for normal pages, but not for blogs. Can anyone shed any light?

UPDATE:
It turns out Wordpress uses different pages for blog and normal pages. So I just needed to edit the other pages to match the initial ones, and it all seems to be working now.

Thanks for all of those who took the time to read my questions, sorry if it wasn't too clear or logical. But thanks anyway. All is good!